# Calculating the area of geometry in Feature Collection in Google Earth Engine for Globfire FinalPerimeters Dataset

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

From the dataset description for [Globfire FinalPerimeters](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/JRC_GWIS_GlobFire_v2_FinalPerimeters#description), "area" of the burnt area should have been provided in the feature collection.

However, the area of the fire events were not provided along after checking the metadata of the feature collection.

```
Object (4 properties)
FDate: Float
IDate: Float
Id: Integer
system:index: String
```

I am trying to calculate the area of the geometry of each feature in the feature collection. Some of them works fine, but I found a number of "infinity" value for the area exist for most of the polygons with the following coordinates, and I have no idea what does this mean and how should I proceed from here.

```
geometry: Polygon, 5 vertices
type: Polygon
coordinates: List (1 element)
0: List (5 elements)
0: [-180,-90]
1: [180,-90]
2: [180,90]
3: [-180,90]
4: [-180,-90]
```

Links to the modified code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/f729d9d51682d106bf660142620691a5

```
// initial code example: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/JRC_GWIS_GlobFire_v2_FinalPerimeters#description

var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('JRC/GWIS/GlobFire/v2/FinalPerimeters');
var visParams = {
  palette: ['f5ff64', 'b5ffb4', 'beeaff', 'ffc0e8', '8e8dff', 'adadad'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 600000000.0,
  opacity: 0.8,
};

// added the following codes to calculate the area of each feature (geometry) in the feature collection
// however, some feature are showing "infinity" in the area values 
var computeArea = function (f) {
  return f.set({'area': f.area()});
}
dataset = dataset.map(computeArea);
print('First feature:', dataset.first());

// the following code seems to be giving issue, as the "area" properties is not defined in final perimeters
// it is only defined in the daily perimeters dataset (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/JRC_GWIS_GlobFire_v2_DailyPerimeters)
var image = ee.Image().float().paint(dataset, 'area');
Map.addLayer(image, visParams, 'GlobFire Final');
Map.addLayer(dataset, null, 'for Inspector', false);
Map.setCenter(-122.121, 38.56, 12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be some problems with the dataset.  I filed a bug.
One easy thing to do is just filter out any feature that intersects 0,0.  That'll drop the ones with bad geometries.

```
dataset = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.intersects(".geo", ee.Geometry.Point([0,0])).not())
```